# Every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ contains a closed set

Tags: real-analysis

I have to

> Show that every open set  in $\mathbb{R}$ contains a closed set

My proof is:

Case 1) Take an open interval $(a,b).$ Either there exists an $x \in (a,b)$ such that $a < x < b$ or not. So, if   $a < x < b$, $\{x\}$ is a closed set in $(a,b).$ If there doesn't exist such an $x,$ then, the interior of $(a,b)$ is the empty set, which is a closed set (it is also an open set, but that is not relevant).

Case 2) If the open interval is infinite, I could also pick a singleton set contained in it.

I particularily think that it could be incorrect to say that "If there doesn't exist such an $x,$ then, the interior of $(a,b)$ is the empty set," but I am not sure.

And also, judging by the complexity of another answer to the same question, [Does every open interval of $\mathbb{R}$ contain a closed interval?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1999579/does-every-open-interval-of-mathbbr-contain-a-closed-interval),  I beleive that my proof is missing some reasonings and understanding about what I need to prove, and that I am wrong about the whole thing.

Comment: Every open set contains the emptyset, which is closed. :)

Comment: Your case 1 argument assumes without saying it that every open set includes an interval.  This is true for all open sets except the empty set.  You should be asking that $(a,b)$ is inside the open set.  You don't need case 2 because even if the open set includes an infinite interval it includes a finite interval and you can go back to case 1.

Comment: Going off cornman's comment your proof would at the very least have to include a case for the empyset, which is both closed and open (called clopen sometimes). Observing that the empty set contains itself settles that part. As cornman suggested, this could be a one sentence proof by using the empty set as the closed set for all of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ an open set. If $U=\emptyset$, is closed and we finish. If not, let $x\in U$ and, because is open, exist $\epsilon>0$ such that $I=(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset U$. Now, consider the closed interval $[x-\frac{\epsilon}{2},x+\frac{\epsilon}{2}]\subset I \subset U$ and we finish.

Answer (score 4):

Every open set contains the empty set, which is closed.

Answer (score 2):

**Every** set in $\mathbb{R}$ contains a closed set.

Every non-empty set in $\mathbb{R}$ contains a non-empty closed set, just take the singleton of some point it contains.